Ubuntu 22.04 rt just rebooted itself
we're running Ubuntu 22.04 real time kernel on a miniPC. It's been running great, unattended, for several weeks.
This morning it simply rebooted itself. I've looked through logs in /var/logs (dmseg, kern, etc.) and I find entries up to the moment of reboot, but no errors indicating any issues, then the logs continue after the reboot with the normal startup entries.
The PC is kind of mission-critical at our radio station (it handles processing the audio for the FM broadcast) and if it stops, then listener hear dead air.
I'd like to dig more deeply into this but don't know how to proceed. Tips would be very helpful. Thank you!

Good job reviewing your logs! Nothing logged suggests a possible hardware fault. Perhaps a rare power fluctuation. The two most common causes of unexpected reboots are overheating and faulty power supply. You can check for overheating and unobstructed vents easily yourself. Power supply is harder, and requires a pattern of reboots to spot.

Some enterprise intended hardware contains hardware logs too that will provide details on why reboots, shutdowns & powerups are triggered. Those logs may say something like software if the OS controls it (where you need to explore OS logs as you attempted), but will provide clues if the hardware caused reset (ie. bad power, overheat etc which are issues the OS may not be fully aware of thus won't exist in OS logs). Hardware logs are machine (firmware) specific.

Thank you both for your insight. user535733 points out that a power supply fault could be what happened (the device is not running hot), that's certainly a possibility, but the PC's BIOS does not offer the option to automatically restart on resumption of power. So it should have just shut down. My seat-of-the-pants guess is some other hardware failure because if it was software, the OS should have written panic messages, or at least SOME trouble messages to the logs before folding up its tent and simply rebooted. Does this make sense?

Guessing: Can you possibly pinpoint any special event in the data it handled at that time? Causing a memory full or some similar event?

"if it was software, the OS should have written panic messages, or at least SOME trouble messages to the logs" Kudos again! Yes, developers try to log every software failure they can think of. The reboot instead of shutdown is indeed curious.

Look at  sudo journalctl  -b -1 to see logs leading up to shutdown. If there's nothing there, suspect power or overheating, which can kill a system before the software gets a clue.
